# Are " replacement rules" and " inference rules" ( in natural deduction) really two kinds of rules?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I think the distinction, in natural deduction systems,  between " inference rules" and " replacement rules" is standard. ( For example, Bergmann, The Logic Book).

Is " replacement rule" anything else than " inference rule that works in both direction".

For example is the replacement rule  " P :: ~ ~ P " ( Double negation) anything else than an abbreviation for

" (1) from P, infer ~ ~P

AND

(2) from ~~P  , infer P "   ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two sets of rules are importantly different:

1. First of all, as you noted, a rule of inference go one way, but a rule of replacement goes both ways, because rules of replacement reflect *equivalences*
2. Second, rules of replacement can be applied to *component* parts of a larger statement ... but rules of inference *cannot*.

For example, using Double Negation I can infer $\neg \neg P$ from $P$, and vice versa ... but I can *also* infer $\neg \neg P \land Q$ from $P \land Q$, and vice versa. That is, replacement (equivalence) rules can be applied to part of a statement.

On the other hand, rules of inference should *not* be applied to component parts! (doing so is a common mistake for beginning students of logic!)

For example, if I try to infer $A \to C$ from $(A \land B) \to C$ using Conjunction Elimination, I am making an invalid inference (check it with a truth-table).  So: Rules of inference can only be applied to *whole* statements.

Answer (score 5):

Rules of replacement are equivalences.   You generate a new statement by replacing a clause *within* a statement with a logically equivalent clause.   As you noted, this process may always be reversed.

$$\begin{split}p\to (q\to r)\\\hline p\to(\lnot q\lor r)\end{split}$$

Rules of inference are entailments.   The rules are used to infer that a new statement may be logically implied by one *or more* statements.   However the converse is not always allowable.   Rules of inference also cannot be applied to clauses of a statement, they always work on whole statements; and revolve around the operator with the highest precedence.

$$\begin{split}p\to r&\quad p\\\hline r&\end{split}$$